# Why did this departure from Buenos Aires seem to delay heading northeast?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-path

[image]

It was going from Argentina to Germany and after takeoff it went over a town and then it went direct to Germany. Why did it go over the town instead of going directly to Germany?

[Source](https://www.flightradar24.com/56.2)

Comment: Which runway did you takeoff from? 11?

Comment: @aeroalias Yes I think so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's following a [departure procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_instrument_departure_(SID)).

[image]

([chart source](http://uvairlines.com/admin/resources/charts/SAEZ.pdf))

The path flown matches the route described for departing Runway 11 with the La Plata 6B departure.

See the [map here](https://skyvector.com/?ll=-34.82778299304897,-58.105224601779156&chart=301&zoom=4) to visually match up the described departure procedure with the flown path.

Comment: The reason this SID is designed this way? Noise prevention and not overflying Buenos Aires?